# Reference numbers, and using them to compare numbers in text file

Tags: c#

The project is based on Eye Tracker. Let me brief the idea behind the project to understand my problem better.

I have the hardware of Tobii C eye tracker. This eye tracker will be able to give out coordinates of the X, Y of where I am looking at. But this device is very sensitive. When I look at 1 point, the eye tracker will send out many different data of coordinates but within `± 100` range which I found out. Even though you are staring at 1 point, your eyes keep moving, therefore giving out many data. This many data (float numbers) are then saved in a text file. Now I only need 1 data (X coordinate) which signifies the 1 point I am staring instead of the many data which are within the `± 100` range and move it to a new text file.

I have no idea how I should code to do that.

These are the `float` numbers in the text file.

```
200
201
198
202
250
278
310
315
360
389
500
568
579
590
```

When I stare at point 1, the data are `200-300`, which are within the `± 100` range. I wanna set the `200` as reference point subtracts itself with the next number and check if the resultant value within `100`, if it is, remove them. The reference point should keep doing that to the following numbers until it reaches outside the `± 100` range. Once outside the `100` range, now the number is `310`, then now this number is the next reference point and do the same and subtract with the following numbers below and check if the resultant value within `100`. Once outside the `100` range, the next number is `500`, now, that is the new reference point, and do the same. That is my objective. To put it to simpler terms, The reference points should be moved into a new file.

This is my code so far which get the gaze coordinates and stores them in a  text file.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using Tobii.Interaction;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

class Program
{

    private static void programintro()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Keys To Start");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        programintro();
        Console.ReadKey();
        double currentX = 0.0;
        double currentY = 0.0;
        double timeStampCurrent = 0.0;
        double diffX = 0.0;
        double diffY = 0.0;
        int counter = 0;
        var host = new Host();
        host.EnableConnection();
        var gazePointDataStream = host.Streams.CreateGazePointDataStream();
        gazePointDataStream.GazePoint((gazePointX, gazePointY, timestamp) =>

        {
            diffX = gazePointX - currentX;
            diffY = gazePointY - currentY;
            currentX = gazePointX;
            currentY = gazePointY;
            timeStampCurrent = timestamp;
            if (diffX > 100 || diffX <= -100 || diffY >= 100 || diffY <= -100)
            {
                counter++;
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C: \\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\FYP 2019\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile1.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Recorded Data " + counter + "\n=================================================================================================================\nX: {0} Y:{1}\nData collected at {2}", currentX, currentY, timeStampCurrent);
                    writer.WriteLine("=================================================================================================================");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Recorded Data " + counter + "\n=================================================================================================================\nX: {0} Y:{1}\nData collected at {2}", currentX, currentY, timeStampCurrent);
                Console.WriteLine("=================================================================================================================");
            }
        });
        //host.DisableConnection();
        while (true)
        {
            if (counter <  10)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {

                Environment.Exit(0);

            }
        }
```

> Now my Question is how do I code to read the text file and set a
>   reference number and subtracts itself with the next number and check
>   if the resultant value within `100` and have a new reference number if
>   it outside the `± 100` range. Those reference numbers are then stored in
>   a new text file.

If there is a code example, I will create a new programme and store there and test it out first.

Comment: give a sample scenario using `set a reference number and subtracts itself with the next number and check if the resultant value within 100`

Comment: Thats the one i mentioned i do not know how to do

Comment: you can try it like this - Use loop with StreamReader.ReadLine() to get the numbers from file and trim and parse them to perform the operation.

Comment: how do i do the trim and parse to perform the operation, i am a novice.

Comment: If the file will contain tracking data where you stare at different points over time, you probably want some statistical tools like K-means clustering analysis. If you only have 1 reference point per file, wouldn't something simple as average work pretty well? Probably again with some statistical methods, like removing outliers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial data is present in a list, the logic to get all reference points is as follows:

```
var initialData = new List<float> {  200,201,198,202,250,278,310,315,360,389,500,568,579,590  };

var lstReferencePoints = new List<float>();
var referencePoint = default(float);
foreach(var num in initialData)
{
    if(referencePoint == default(float))
    {
        referencePoint = num;
    }
    if(Math.Abs(referencePoint - num) > 100)
    {
        lstReferencePoints.Add(referencePoint);
        referencePoint = num;
    }
}

lstReferencePoints.Add(referencePoint);
```

`lstReferencePoints` contains the list of referencePoints.

**Edit: reading the float numbers from a text file to a List**

```
var pointsArray = File.ReadAllLines(your_file_path);
var initialData = new List<float>(pointsArray.Select(float.Parse));
```

**Storing the `lstReferencePoints` to a new text file:**

```
using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("newFile_Path"))
{
   foreach (var item in lstReferencePoints)
      tw.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yr help, but i do not want to list down all the numbers in the code as actually there are over 100 numbers. Instead i wanna read those numbers from the textfile and do the operation.

Comment: @user11612402 added code to convert text file entries to `List<float>` and then writing the reference points to a new file. Please see the edit.

Comment: Aight i will try and get back to you